# splitting multiple columns using lambda

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to split the values in these columns but it keeps returning "list index out of range"

````
for c in new_col:
    df1[c] = df1[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
    df2[c] = df2[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[1])```


Input In [46], in <lambda>(x)
      4 for c in new_col:
      5     df1[c] = df1[c].apply(lambda x: x.split("/")[0])
----> 6     df2[c] = df2[c].apply(lambda x: ***x.split("/")[1])***

IndexError: list index out of range
````

Answer (score 0):

You are likely passing an input that cannot be split by "/". If you want to debug easily, add a print statement in the loop which prints out df2[c] at the top of the loop, and then you can see if the issue is with df2 or with the contents of df2.

edit: By that I mean, you are assuming that the contents of df1 and df2 are always in the form "something/something", but as the error is in the second lambda function that the index is out of range it means the split array has size = 1, which will be the case for any value that cannot be split by the separator (x.split("/")[0] == df2[c]).

Comment: The whole column is separated by a slash, so that should work. it runs somewhere else but not my notebook, I don't know why

Comment: @BlessingEzinne can you add that print statement to print df2[c] and include the last output before it errors out?